# Create MANOVA tables for publication using R?

Tags: r, stargazer, sjplot, manova

I was wondering whether its possible to generate APA/publishable tables for MANOVA in R?

There are various packages and methods (e.g. 'sjPlot', 'stargazer', 'apaTables') that seem to do the job for different forms of ANOVA and regression. It may simply be a case of entering the data/model/object in the right way for one of these methods, but although I've played around with it, I can't figure out how to do it.

I have conducted a MANOVA on a series of species for depth and year, and I would like to display the overall result (summary), and the results for each species (summary.aov) as a single table or as two - either would be fine.

Here's a simplified example of my data, and the two outputs I would like to make into a table.

```
### data example 

depth.1 <- c(0, 2, 6, 10)

Depth <- c(replicate(40, depth.1))

Year <- c(replicate(40, 2016), replicate(40, 2017), replicate(40, 2018), replicate(40, 2019))

sp.1 <- runif(160, min = 0, max = 100) 

sp.2 <- runif(160, min = 0, max = 100)

sp.3 <- runif(160, min = 0, max = 100)

sp.4 <- runif(160, min = 0, max = 100)

sp.5 <- runif(160, min = 0, max = 100) 

data <- data.frame(Depth, Year, sp.1, sp.2, sp.3, sp.4, sp.5)

### MANOVA examples

data.man <- manova(cbind(sp.1, sp.2, sp.3, sp.4, sp.5) ~ Depth + Year, data = data) 

summary(data.man)

summary.aov(data.man)
```

Thanks for any help or advice!